# How to properly validate CSRF Token in Yii2?

Tags: php, html, security, yii2, csrf

I use `enableCsrfValidation` on my main config

```php
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
            'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'cookieValidationKey' => '[somerandomstring]',
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'hostInfo' => YII_ENV_PROD ? Yii::$app->params['hostInfo'] : null,
            'csrfCookie' => [
                'httpOnly' => true,
                'secure' => YII_ENV_PROD,
                'sameSite' => 'Lax',
            ],
        ],
```

and here is one of the controller's action (to change the user's `fullName`)

```php
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new ProfileForm();
    $model->fullName = Yii::$app->user->identity->full_name;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Profile updated successfully.');
        return $this->refresh();
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

here is my `profile/index` view

```php
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'horizontal']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'fullName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

From the rendered HTML page, we already get the _csrf param and token, in both the header and the form.

[image: rendered HTML page]

My question is why, from the penetration testing, the attacker still can submit the form using GET method and change the value of user's fullName, even without submitting the csrf token in the form and/or the header (image taken from the BurpSuite application)?

[image: still can change the value of Profile's fullName]

Note:
The issue also happens on other controller/action as well, generated from the Gii.

Comment: I wondering if Yii2 only cares about POST method when validating the csrf token value, but the `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {` can be used on a GET request too.

Comment: Another way you can define in the behavior to receive just this kind of request for this action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSRF token is not validated for `GET`, `HEAD` or `OPTIONS` request.

The problem with your code is that Yii2 by default tries to parse request body even for `GET` requests.

That's why if you send body with `GET` request `Yii::$app->request->post()` call will return non-empty array. Submitted data are loaded to model and it's saved.

If you want to be sure data are saved only for `POST` requests you should use `Yii::$app->request->isPost` or `Yii::$app->request->getIsPost()` in your condition.
For example like this:

```php
if (
    Yii::$app->request->isPost
    && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) 
    && $model->save()
) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have a similar thought and will try to re-test the case.

Comment: Another way you can define in the behavior to receive just this kind of request for this action

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco yes, you can use `yii\filters\VerbFilter` behavior if you want to limit access to action only through specific method. But, that won't work if you want same action to serve form on `GET` request and process submitted form on `POST` request.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Yeah, you are right.